# My visual studio script doesn't change any attributes in the form

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to change the text in a textBox with the press of a button (start) but nothing happens when I click it. Is there anything wrong with how I'm doing it?

```
    private void start_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        start.Text = "Hello world";
    }
```

EDIT: Here's the complete cs code of the form:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
            private void start_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            start.Text = "Ciao";
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this event handler is set up to handle the click event of that button?

Comment: Show more code in order for others to get whats wrong

Comment: Put a breakpoint at that line and see if it gets hit.

Comment: Is there a way to create an event from the UI?

Comment: @MarcoGiacomin For a button, just (double) click it. Or go to it's properties, select "events" and find "onClick"

Comment: @HansKesting Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click right your project in your solution explorer then click the ´Set as StartUp Project´
or

Click ´Any CPU´ that on the tool bar the click **Configuration Manager** and check the Build checkbox is checked.If it's not checked, check it.